# User able to see data associated with their regional office in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, filter

I am new to sharepoint.

My system has various users and each one is assigned to a regional office. I only want users to be able to see data that is associated with their regional office.

I only want the users to be able to manipulate or view  objects from their own region.
How can I do this in sharepoint.

Can somebody please help me......

Answer (score 0):

The answer differs depending on what version of SharePoint you have. If you have MOSS, you can use "Target audiences" here (however, be warned that audience targeting just **hides** the item and users can still see it, if they use the direct url of an item).

Create an audience for each regional office and let the users assign items to audiences. To be sure that all items have the "target audiences" set, create an event handler that checks if the "taret audience" field is set in each item, if not - set it according to the current user.

If you have plain WSS or do not want just to hide but rather disallow access to items, you will have to `BreakRoleInheritance` on all items and set permissions to all of them according to regional office the author comes from. You can do it in an eventhandler or in New/Edit form, your code options can be found here: [Sharepoint - Capture save event of NewForm.aspx/Edit.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040699/sharepoint-capture-save-event-of-newform-aspx-edit-aspx/2040800#2040800)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do:

1. Create a SharePoint group for each region.
2. Add the users or the AD groups (better) to the proper regional group.
3. Go to your site, library/list, folder, or item/document/file and modify the permission so only certain group can see certain item.